# Rails: Scope parent model by attribute of child

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm having a tough time figuring something out in Rails. It probably has to do with my very limited knowledge of SQL, since I know Rails pretty well. I'm using Rails 5.

I have two models: Applicant and Application.

```
class Applicant < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :application
  has_many :skills

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :application
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :skills, 
    reject_if: ->(skill) { skill[:name].empty? || skill[:experience].empty? }

  validates_with ApplicantValidator
 end

class Application < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :applicant
  has_many :notes

  VALID_STATUSES = ["in review", "accepted", "declined", "closed"]

  validates_length_of   :why_interested, minimum: 25
  validates             :accept_terms, acceptance: true
  validates             :status, inclusion: { in: VALID_STATUSES }

  before_validation :set_status

  private

  def set_status
    self.status ||= "in review"
  end
end
```

I'd like to add a scope, `:active`, to the Applicant model that returns only applicants who have an application whose status is "in review". However, I can't find a way to access the application within a scope proc.

I've seen other suggestions for cases where there is a `has_many` relationship with the child, but they didn't work in my case.

I doubt it makes a difference, but I'm using Postgres. The closest I've come to a solution is to add this, but when I run RSpec it says there needs to be a FROM-clause for the applications table. I don't know how to effect that.

```
scope :active, -> { joins(:application).where('"application"."status" = "in review"') }
```

Comment: Double quotes in SQL are used for quoting identifiers (such as table and column names), single quotes are for string literals, also the table name will be plural. You'd want to say `where('"applications"."status" = 'in review'')` or better `where(applications: { status: 'in review' })` so that ActiveRecord takes are of the quoting.

Comment: I changed it to `scope :active, -> { joins(:application).where({ applications: { status: "in review" } }) }`, and it's no longer raising an error, but the scope returns empty when it shouldn't.

Comment: What should it be finding that it isn't? You can also use `where(id: Application.select(:applicant_id).where(status: 'in review'))` but that should produce the same result for a `has_one` association.

Comment: Interesting - looks like the second way works in the Rails console but not in RSpec. I think the issue must be with my factories. Thanks!

Comment: Both versions should do the same thing with a `has_one`. The second one tends to work better with `has_many` associations because it avoids duplicates that a JOIN can introduce.

Comment: You're right, it does. It turned out I was using `let` instead of `let!` to create my models in RSpec so there just weren't any in the database when the tests ran. D'oh.

Answer (score 1):

```
scope :in_review_applicants, -> { joins(:application).where('application.status = ?', :in_review) }
```

I think is something like that..

Comment: That gets me an error that says, `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "application"`, which is the same as what the scope I added did.

Comment: change application for applications

Comment: I tried that too, I got `ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Can't join 'Applicant' to association named 'applications'; perhaps you misspelled it?`

Comment: You use the association name with `joins` but the table name in the `where`: `joins(:application).where('applications.status = ?', :in_review)` or `joins(:application).where(applications: { status: :in_review })`.

Comment: You have to change to the table name, joins(:applications).where('applications.status.....

Or with includes { includes(:application).where(applications: { status: :in_review }).references(:applications)